# How to extend any Core Directive, Service, Class of Angular2?

Tags: angular

How we can extend or use same defination of Core Directive, Service, Class with few new features?

Lets say we want to create new **routerLink** directive which only has few more **event listerner** property and more methods for its class.

One more thing, when I am trying to do so OR try to start,

From angular.io I got reference for this on github "https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-beta.1/modules/angular2/src/router/router_link.ts#L6-L84".

But when I tried to find same file in local downloaded files then found like no such file exist on path(angular2/src/router/router_link.ts).

Whereas there is file exist **angular2/src/router/router_link.d.ts** but its content are different as compare to github source.

Can anyone also provide guidline for same also as well extend or recreate own directive on top of CORE?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the services/components/etc can all be extended fairly easily.

I extend the RouterOutlet to allow me to use my own Auth service which I inject into the new outlet:

```
import {Directive, Attribute, ElementRef, DynamicComponentLoader, Inject} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, RouterOutlet, ComponentInstruction} from 'angular2/router';
import {UserService} from '../../services/user_service';
//import {LoginCmp} from '../login/login';

@Directive({
  selector: 'router-outlet'
})
export class LoggedInRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
  public user: any;
  private parentRouter: Router;

  constructor(_elementRef: ElementRef, _loader: DynamicComponentLoader,
              _parentRouter: Router, @Attribute('name') nameAttr: string, @Inject(UserService) user:UserService) {
    super(_elementRef, _loader, _parentRouter, nameAttr);
    this.user = user;
    this.parentRouter = _parentRouter;
  }

  activate(instruction: ComponentInstruction) {
    var url = instruction.urlPath;
    if (!this.user.publicRoutes[url] && !this.user.isAuth()) {
      // todo: redirect to Login, may be there a better way?
    console.log('Component Redirecting from:', url);
      this.parentRouter.navigate([this.user.baseRoute]);
    }
    return super.activate(instruction);
  }
}
```

The original is [here from Auth0](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-authentication-sample/blob/master/src/app/LoggedInOutlet.ts) but is a bit outdated with the alpha/beta switch

**As to the source code, I think you are looking for the precompiled code which is written in TypeScript**

When you get it from NPM or whatever it's run through the compiler already.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Dennis, this does not work with RC4 (which was released on 30th June, 2016). How to get this working with this version?

Comment: @SatishMadiwal I haven't had a chance to look at RC4, but which part isn't working for you? The extension or the router code? The new router is very different from the example I gave. If you are trying to protect routes heres a great tutorial: http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html

Comment: yeah, I have followed this from angular.io website : [CanActivate Guarding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#can-activate-guard).This class needs to be rewritten by following the canActivate guide. I was able to do that today. Thanks!